# C# SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>.Contains ( T, IEqualityComparer<T> )

Tags: c#, contains, iequalitycomparer

When I call:

```
SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>.Contains ( T, IEqualityComparer<T> )
```

it fails to call:

```
IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals(T x, T y)
```

I have sample code here:

https://github.com/user7251/repo1/blob/master/SynchReadOnlyList_Demo/SynchReadOnlyList_Demo/SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection_Demo.cs

It executes this line:

```
bool r = _order.Products.Contains ( p, Product.s_ProductByNameEqualityComparer );
```

So it should execute this line:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine ( string.Concat ( "ProductByNameEqualityComparer.Equals(){", x.Name, "}{", y.Name, "}" ) );
```

But it writes nothing to the console.  Any ideas?

Comment: It would be a lot more useful if you spent a little time writing a short but complete program that isolates the problem, and include that in your post, instead of linking to an external source.

Comment: I already did that: https://github.com/user7251/repo1/tree/master/SynchReadOnlyList_Demo

Comment: What's wrong with linking to the code on GitHub?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *"don't just copy in your entire program ... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem"*, and *"but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."*

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1. The single parameter constructor of `SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>` takes a syncRoot `object`, not the underlying collection, take a look at the documentation around the constructors [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404423(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Unlike other read-only collection wrappers, the `SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>` also takes a snapshot of the provided collection rather than keeping a reference to the underlying collection, this can be seen in the source code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection.cs,39).

Being perfectly honest, I can't imagine ever using `SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>`, if it maintained a reference to the underlying collection it could have some use, but as it takes a snapshot, it seems 100% useless to me, why lock around a resource which can only be read from? That and the fact it doesn't even implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, I wouldn't bother trying to use it.

There is perhaps a use-case when deriving from this type and using the `Items` property to mutate the underlying collection, however I have seen no examples which do this.

Comment: I incorrectly passed a List instead of an "object syncRoot".  My fault, but I think the SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection ctor should not take an "object syncRoot".  Instead, it should take a "Lock syncRoot" for type safety, where Lock is simply a "class Lock : object {}".  Or better yet, it should use a ReaderWriterLockSlim.

Comment: @user1074214 The ctor with the `makeCopy` param is internal, so you can't use that.

Comment: The ctor with the makeCopy param should be public.

Comment: It makes sense to use a ReaderWriterLockSlim because it shares the lock with code outside of the SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection.

Comment: @user1074214 It sounds like you would be better off implementing your own version of `SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>`, or better yet, use [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My original plan was to develop my own version of SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection.  As a first step, I started to write a demo to show the shortcoming of SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection.  That demo led me to create this stackoverflow page.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no items in `Order.Products`.  You add items to the internal `_products` list but you never change `_productsSol`.

`_productsSol = new SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<Product> ( _products );}` creates a new readonly collection with the **current** contents of _products which is empty.  It doesn't update its contents when `_products` changes.  It wouldn't be a read only collection if it did.

Comment: SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection has a reference to the original List.  It doesn't copy the list.

Comment: Nope it copies the list.  See the reference source for yourself.   https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection.cs

Comment: ReadOnlyCollection<T> copies a reference to the list.  It does not copy the data structure.  I mistakenly assumed that SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T> did the same.